# Changing the values of captured variables inside the c++ lambda

Tags: c++

I am trying to increment a captured variable to a lambda function by reference but unable to do so.

By capturing the variable by value and then making the lambda mutable, I am able to increment the value. But by passing the reference, the increment is not getting applied.

Also,
In case of capture by value, how the value is getting updated across the calls to inc(). Is this similar to closure in JS?

```
**Capture By reference**

auto inc_count(int x){
    return [&x](){
        return x++;
    };
};

int main()
{
    auto inc = inc_count(4);
    cout<<inc()<<endl;    //32765
    cout<<inc()<<endl;    //32765
    cout<<inc()<<endl;    //32765
    cout<<inc()<<endl;    //32765

    return 0;
}


**Capture by value**

auto inc_count(int x){
    return [x]()mutable{
        return x++;
    };
};

int main()
{
    auto inc = inc_count(4);
    cout<<inc()<<endl;     //4
    cout<<inc()<<endl;     //5
    cout<<inc()<<endl;     //6
    cout<<inc()<<endl;     //7

    return 0;
}
```

Actual Output :
`32765`
`32765`
`32765`
`32765`

Expected Output :
`4`
`5`
`6`
`7`

Comment: Think about `auto inc_count(int x){
    return [&x](){
        return x++;
    };
};`.  What do you capture by reference?  When you return from the function, is that thing still alive?

Comment: To fix it you can change `inc_count()` parameter type to `int &` but will have to pass lvalue to it, not int constant

Answer (score 6):

In the first version, you are capturing a reference to a variable that is not alive after the function returns. You have a dangling reference after the function returns and your code has undefined behavior.

You can use the following to capture by reference.

```
auto inc_count(int& x){
    return [&x](){
        return x++;
    };
};
```

But then, you can't use `int_count(4)` in `main`. You'll have to use a variable whose reference can be used in `int_count`.

```
int main()
{
    int number = 4;
    auto inc = inc_count(number);

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Missed it completely. I just have one more doubt. In case of capture by value, how the value is getting updated across the calls to inc(). Is this similar to closure in JS?

Comment: @SubhashJha • capture by value means the lambda object has its own local member variable, and that is what is being updated.  A lambda is just a large amount of syntactic sugar, which makes a functor object.  Writing them without the sugar is a lot of boilerplate code, which was a barrier for people making them.

Comment: @SubhashJha, I am not familiar with JS enough to compare. In this case, the lambda has its own copy of the variable, which is incremented when it gets called.

Comment: @SubhashJha JavaScript automatically extends the lifetime of the captured variable, c++ does not. C++ standards says: `the validity of such captures is determined by the lifetime of the object to which thereference refers, not by the lifetime of the reference itself.`

Answer (score 0):

In this function, you receive `x` as a copy of some argument.

```
auto inc_count(int x){
    return [&x](){
        return x++;
    };
};
```

When you return from `inc_count`, the `x` being referenced by your returned value, `&x`, is destroyed. This is why your value is close to the maximum `short` value, 32,767. The memory at the address you are attempting to access has been freed and no longer contains any data structure.

Your pass by value works because the memory is not being freed. You are passing a copy of your data at each point; the program is not freeing this data and you end up with a coherent value.